# ADF Skin.css -customizing issues

Tags: css, customization, html, oracle-adf, skin

I am working on ADF skin.css to create a customized web page. Lot of customizations that I do on the skin.css does not seem to reflect on the pages appropriately. For example, when i try to apply a gradient effect to a Panel Stretch Layout, it does not appear. Can anyone help with a good guide on how to go about this?

Thanks,
Geetha

Answer (score 2):

Even though I am not an HTML expert, what I've found most effective is to look at generated HTML using Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

To shrink HTML size, ADF compresses the names stylesheet classes e.g.:

```
class="x10" and class="x2e"
```

But if you remove this compression, you will start to see in html something like this:

```
class="af_inputComboboxListOfValues_dropdown-table"
```

And this can be controlled through skinning like this:

```
af|inputComboboxListOfValues::dropdown-table {
    height:350px;
}
```

To disable CSS style compression, you need to place this cod snippet on your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.DISABLE_CONTENT_COMPRESSION</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks..very useful while i was trying to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start by working with the skin editor - here is a quick intro to what it can do - https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_faces_skin_editor_how